# Nuxt 3 omit part of url for a dynamic page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I am using ***nuxt3*** with content and have a directory called `planets` in my content folder.

Inside the planets folder I have all my planet files.

In my `pages` dir I have a planets folder with a catch-all vue file called `[...planet].vue`

Now, when I go to any one planet page it goes to this url `/planets/<planet-name>` but I would like to omit the `/planets/` part and have the url be just the planet name eg. `mydomain.ext/mercury`.

I found in the [docs](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/directory-structure/pages/#using-approuteroptions) that you can override routes, but whatever I do
in the `router.options.ts` file, nothing happens and I havent found
any info or examples on how I can console.log or debug that file, to find if its even working, the router options file resides in my projects root.

Secondly I found that the [hooks](https://github.com/nuxt/framework/discussions/5070) option in `nuxt.config.ts` is used, and with that I tried this:

`nuxt.config.ts`

```js
hooks: {
  'pages:extend' (pages) {
    pages.push({
      name: 'mercury',
      path: '/mercury',
      file: resolve(__dirname, './planets/[..planet].vue')
    })
  }
}
```

But I get an error that this file doesnt exist.

I got a little bit closer with using `useRoute` in my `[...planets].vue` but I cant get it to connect the page and the catch-all page.

Comment: Why not use a `[planet].vue`? Either that one or the catch all should be working fine with no specific customization needed in `nuxt.config.ts` IMO.

Comment: Im unsure I follow, I have my planet files in `content/planets/...` which means each planets url will be `/planets/<planet>` i need the planets files to be separate in the planets dir since i'll have other different views for eg. the about page.

Comment: If you want an about page, you create an `about.vue` file, for the rest you can call your content in any page that you'd like.

Comment: I didnt specify that I would want my about content to also come from a  `/content/about`. 
But i took your advice, moved all my planets + about yaml files to content and also moved the  `[planet].vue` to just pages.
I added  ` <ContentDoc  path="/about" v-slot="{ doc }">`  to my `about.vue` and got it working as I wanted it, thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Ideally it would be nice to have my planets and other data files separated though.
I know I've done something similar with eleventy that you have data folder which has a site.yml file from which I fetch site title and other data necessary data, i wonder if such a thing  exists in nuxt ?

Comment: I didn't used Content v2 but you probably can filter with a query to fetch only from specific folder or with a specific name (like in v1). I've got some answers related to that one if you really need it.

Comment: You file is called `[...planet].vue`. However, you're referencing `[..planet].vue`.